# Is it correct to install one Insight Tag (LinkedIn Pixel) for domain and subdomain?

Tags: linkedin-api

My name is Vitaliy.
I am a digital marketer at my company, and I want to install Insight Tag to a website to track conversions.
We have our main website: https://qatestlab.com/

But it has also a subdomain for the blog: https://blog.qatestlab.com/

Can you please specify, should I install two different tags on these domains or just one, the same for both?

## linkedin

Comment: I'd like to know this too...please update if you learn more.